# Cannot load keras model with custom constraint

Tags: python, keras

I created a custom constraint for my keras GRU-NN and was able to train my network with it. The constraint looks as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.constraints import Constraint

class WeightClip(Constraint):
    def __init__(self, mn=0.1, mx=1.0):
        self.mn = mn
        self.mx = mx

    def __call__(self, p):
        return K.clip(p, self.mn, self.mx)

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            'name': self.__class__.__name__,
            'minimum': self.mn, 
            'maximum': self.mx
        }
```

After saving the model and trying to reload it with

```
model = keras.models.load_model(modelFile, custom_objects={'WeightClip': WeightClip})
```

I got this error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

The model itself looks like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(
    params.recurrent_units, 
    activation='linear',
    input_shape=(pr.n_features, pr.feature_size), 
    dropout=params.dropout, name='net',
    kernel_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0),
    bias_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0)
))
model.add(Dense(
    1, 
    activation='sigmoid', 
    kernel_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0),
    bias_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0)
))
```

Referring to other similar questions on stackoverflow, which most of the time are related to custom metrics however, I tried different combinations of the custom_objects parameter, but nothing seems to help. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems to work now. Instead of returning the actual configuration in the get_config function I'm returning empty curly brackets. No idea if it harms the behavior of the model when making predictions, but at the moment that's of no concern for me. If anyone wants to explain, i would still be happy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What happens behind the curtains

When you save a model containing a `custom_object` in `keras`, it will save the reference to the class name, as well as a dictionary containing the objects current configuration. It does so by calling the `.get_config()` method of the custom object instance. This method should therefor return a dictionary with everything necessary to recreate the instance.

After calling `keras.models.load()`, `keras` will load your model and create instances of your custom objects using the saved dictionaries. Lets for a moment assume that `old_object_configuration = weight_clip_instance.get_config()`. `keras` will now build a new instance using `new_weight_clip_instance = WeightClip(**old_object_configuration)`. 
As you return a parameter `name` in your `.get_config()` method, but there is no name parameter in the signature of `WeightClip.__init__()` the Error you see will be raised.

### Does returning an empty dict affect your model?

Using the knowledge from above, we can now predict what happens if your `.get_config()` method returns an empty dictionary. This results in a call to `new_weight_clip_instance = WeightClip({})`. The new instance will have the default values for `mn=0.1` and `mx=1.0`, which is not the desired behavior and leads to hard to find bugs.

### A working example

```
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras import Sequential
from keras.constraints import Constraint
from keras.layers import GRU, Dense


RECURRENT_UNITS = 10
N_FEATURES = 10
FEATURE_SIZE = 50
DROPOUT = 0.5


class WeightClip(Constraint):
    def __init__(self, minimum=0.1, maximum=1.0):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum

    def __call__(self, p):
        return K.clip(p, self.minimum, self.maximum)

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            'minimum': self.minimum,
            'maximum': self.maximum
        }


model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(
    RECURRENT_UNITS,
    activation='linear',
    input_shape=(N_FEATURES, FEATURE_SIZE),
    dropout=DROPOUT,
    name='net',
    kernel_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0),
    bias_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0)
))
model.add(Dense(
    1,
    activation='sigmoid',
    kernel_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0),
    bias_constraint=WeightClip(0.1, 1.0)
))
model.save('mymodel')

model = keras.models.load_model('mymodel', custom_objects={'WeightClip': WeightClip})
```